# knife-windows is definitely installed but bootstrap still fails

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have definitely installed knife-windows. Chef gem list shows knife-windows but when I run bootstrap I'm told it's not installed.

```
sudo -u user -H sh -c "cd /home/user/chef-repo/; chef gem list"
sudo -u user -H sh -c "cd /home/user/chef-repo/; knife bootstrap windows winrm $VMIP  -r 'role[build_server]' -x 'domain\user' -V -P 'password'"
```

**Output**

First command shows: knife-windows (0.8.5, 0.8.3)

Second:

```
INFO: Using configuration from /home/user/.chef/knife.rb
WARNING: Hostname containing 'windows' specified. Please install 'knife-windows' if you are attempting to bootstrap a Windows node via WinRM.
Doing old-style registration with the validation key at /home/user/.chef/myserver-validator.pem...
Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Cheers

Comment: Do you use ChefDK? Can you execute `which knife` using your sudo call?

Comment: Hi, Yes I do and the result of which knife using the sudo call is /usr/bin/knife

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your ChefDK setup is incomplete, because your sudo command calls `/usr/bin/knife` which looks like a rubygems-based `knife`, not ChefDK.

Please make sure to add ChefDK to the $PATH of the user, as described here:
https://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html#add-ruby-to-path

Depending on your setup, you also want to use `sudo -i` to execute the command within a login shell.

Comment: Cheers, made those changes so that the right knife is being used. But still no luck even after running chef gem install knife-windows again.

Comment: Got there in the end. It was down to path issues. I noticed that after removing knife-windows and then reinstalling it it no longer showed up in 'chef gem list'. I did a reinstall of chefdk and was more careful about my Path commands and now it looks much better. Many thanks Roland